# OpenCV Template Match Similar Object

Tags: c++, templates, opencv, matching

I am currently trying to use OpenCV template matching function to detect all similar objects in a given image using a template. However, I am not getting all objects (which are blood cells) to be detected even though they are pretty much similar and identical. I have been searching around on Internet for solution but haven't get any.

The following is my code:

```
cv::Mat ref = cv::imread("c:\\image.jpg");
cv::Mat tpl = cv::imread("c:\\template.jpg");

cv::Mat gref, gtpl;
cv::cvtColor(ref, gref, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::cvtColor(tpl, gtpl, CV_BGR2GRAY);

cv::Mat res(ref.rows-tpl.rows+1, ref.cols-tpl.cols+1, CV_32FC1);
cv::matchTemplate(gref, gtpl, res, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
cv::threshold(res, res, 0.8, 1., CV_THRESH_TOZERO);

while (true)
{
    double minval, maxval, threshold = 0.8;
    cv::Point minloc, maxloc;
    cv::minMaxLoc(res, &minval, &maxval, &minloc, &maxloc);

    if (maxval >= threshold)
    {
        cv::rectangle(
            ref,
            maxloc,
            cv::Point(maxloc.x + tpl.cols, maxloc.y + tpl.rows),
            CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2
        );
        cv::floodFill(res, maxloc, cv::Scalar(0), 0, cv::Scalar(.1), cv::Scalar(1.));
    }
    else
        break;
}

cv::imshow("reference", ref);
```

These are the result and image used:

Given Image

[image: Given Image]

Template

[image: Template]

Result with higher threshold setting (0.8/0.8)

[image: Result]

Result with lower threshold settings (0.6/0.3)

[image]

I am pretty new to template matching, is there a way to make all objects in the image get detected?

I need the template matching to detect the cells in some more complicated image as well.

[image]

Comment: I tried lower the threshold but still not detecting all the objects

Comment: Can you upload res image

Comment: Uploaded a result image with lower threshold setting, still not detecting everything, but getting better.

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case you don't needed to use template matching. You may use only red component to detect blobs instead. If you use OpenCV 3.0+ you may use [`cv::SimpleBlobDetector`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH2fw.jpg).

Anyway, you may implement simple detector using `cv::threshold` and `cv::findContours`. I tried following code:

```
int main()
{
  const int threshVal = 30;
  const int minArea = 15 * 15;
  const int maxArea = 100 * 100;
  cv::Mat img = cv::imread("input.jpg");

  cv::Mat bgr[3];
  cv::split(img, bgr);

  cv::Mat red_img = bgr[2];
  cv::threshold(red_img, red_img, threshVal, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

  vector<vector<Point>> contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
  cv::findContours(red_img, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

  for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
  {
    int area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
    if (area < minArea || area > maxArea)
      continue;

    cv::Rect roi = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
    cv::rectangle(img, roi, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
  }

  cv::imshow("result", img);
  cv::waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

And this code detects all blood cells:

[image]

Of course, you may need to adjust values of three constants (`threshVal`, `minArea`, `maxArea`) to get better results on all your samples.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I used this method before but it doesn't works very well in this kind of image [link](http://i.imgur.com/D0cHxkV.jpg). Most of the cells that are packed together are counted as only 1 cell

Comment: @Woody For that exact reason you have the minArea and maxArea parameters.